# Vagrant dosen't work on os x

Tags: vagrant

I am trying to get my vagrant machine up and running. The only problem is when I run `vagrant up` I get the following error message:

> Vagrant could not detect VirtualBox! Make sure VirtualBox is properly installed.
>   Vagrant uses the `VBoxManage` binary that ships with VirtualBox, and requires
>   this to be available on the PATH. If VirtualBox is installed, please find the
>   `VBoxManage` binary and add it to the PATH environmental variable.

This is a fresh install of vagrant and I have no idea why this error message comes up. 
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I am able to run vagrant straight from virturalbox sby clicking ffon the box name in the GUI.

Comment: Have you installed VirtualBox? https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: Yes. Virturalbox is installed.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. all i had to do was to follow the instructions provided here 9https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/vagrant-chef)